# How do I add border at top and bottom in lstset for code

Tags: listings

I want to have border at top and bottom of my code. I tried setting it in `lstset` as follows:

```
\lstset{frame=topline|bottomline}
```

However it simply removed right side border and kept all borders intact.
When I tried:

```
\lstset{frame=topline}
```

It correctly kept top border removing all others.

Similarly, when I tried:

```
\lstset{frame=bottomline}
```

It correctly kept bottom border removing all others.

How can I combine two?

Comment: `\lstset{frame=tb}` should work. Or alternatively `\lstset{frame=lines}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, the `frame` key accepts the following values:

> `none`,
>
> `leftline`,
>
> `topline`,
>
> `bottomline`,
>
> `lines` (top and bottom),
>
> `single` for single frames,
>
> `shadowbox`.

(See section "2.7 Layout elements"  on page 18 of the `listings` documentation version 1.8d.)

In order to get a top and bottom line, you can thus use the built in `lines` key as follows:

```
\lstset{frame=lines}
```

In addition to the before mentioned, 7 predefined styles, you can also fine tune the lines around the listing by using a combination of `t`, `l`, `r`, and `b`  for single lines or the upper case versions for double lines.

A single line above and below the listing would thus correspond to:

```
\lstset{frame=tb}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual ([page 36](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf)) you have to specify multiple options with single characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Pascal}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=tb] 
  for i:=maxint to 0 do
  begin
    { do nothing } 
  end;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]